# How to obtain the proper utf value from a string C++ through iteration

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently trying to write a text renderer. I have code that procedurally generates an atlas map based on a font up to some number of utf characters (currently up to 0xFF for testing). It also skips the ranges that don;t represent characters (for obvious reasons).

The goal now is to calculate the UV coordinates of a character for each character in a string, for which I need to take an arbitrary string and iterate through every character, obtaining the utf index of that character (which I can then map to the index in the atlas).

However, although for ascii characters the conversion works just fine, UTF characters are all over the place.

If I create a regular string and then iterate over the characters, the utf characters explode into negative representations, in spite the string being printed correctly by cout.

If instead I convert the string to a u32string the code iterates each utf character as 2 characters.

Essentially this:

```
    string str = " ABCDEFGHKabcdefgz¡¥";
    std::u32string input;
    input.clear();
    for(unsigned char c : str) input += c;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> converter;

    for(char32_t c : input)
    {
        std::cout << converter.to_bytes(c) << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
```

Prints:

```
32
A
65
B
66
C
67
D
68
E
69
F
70
G
71
H
72
K
75
a
97
b
98
c
99
d
100
e
101
f
102
g
103
z
122
Â
194
¡
161
Â
194
¥
165
```

Is there a way in C++ to iterate through every utf character (stand alone) and convert it to an unsignrd integer? Ideally I would like to be able to print the character I am parsing to the terminal as well as the code (for debugging).

There's lots of questions on this topic on SO, but none I read described how to convert the characters to indices dynamically.

Comment: Note that `std::wstring_convert` is deprecated since c+-17.

Comment: Great so not even this much was proper... so how do I do this?

Comment: You are not iterating through characters.  If it is UTF-8, you are iterating through encoding units.  If it is UTF-32, you are iterating through code points.  For UTF-8, a code point is one-or-more encoding units, and a character is one-or-more code points.  For UTF-32, a character is one-ore-more code points.

Comment: is there a way for me to iterate over characters?

Comment: Note: UTF isn't specific enough. You could iterate over UTF-32 code units and treat them as Unicode codepoints because they have the same value. But you haven't properly converted from your exec-charset to UTF-32.

Comment: So, what us your exec-charset? (Also make sure your compiler is properly knowledgeable of your source-charset.)

Comment: What is the exec-charset?

Comment: Your compiler must use some character encoding to emit text literals. Consult your compiler documentation and/or command-line arguments. Most allow you to specify the character encoding (and most have a default so it kind of works without you knowing).